# Redirect to previously intended page in laravel after unauthenticated json response through ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication, redirect, exception

I am using AJAX requests to handle some crud operations in my application. In some cases, there may arise a situation where the user is unauthenticated when the user submits an AJAX request, which requires authentication. Now in this scenario, I'll redirect the user to the login page using JavaScript by handling 401 status code sent from the server. However, I also want the user to be redirected to the previous page from where the user was redirected from. For this, I tried this code in the `app\Exceptions\Handler` class given below:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{

    if ($request->expectsJson()){
        $request->session()->put('url.intended', $request->session()->get('_previous.old')   );

        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()] , 401);
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax call laravel web http response on this part:

```
return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

will redirect correctly and load the page but your ajax response will contain html template of the response not url redirect.

To come accross this issue simply do:

```
return response()->json(['redirect'=>['route'=>'/login'], 403);
```

And in ajax part check for `403` response if u get a `403` then simply grab the route from json above and do:

```
windows.location.href=response.data.redirect.route;
```

Comment: So, will the user be redirected to the previous page or the authentication default route ?

Comment: it will be redirected to the route u want to: return redirect()->guest(route('login'));

Comment: Actually, what I meant was will it redirect automatically to the page where the user was sending AJAX request from or will the user be redirected to the default route for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()){
        //put the intended URL into the session data so that the user will
        //get redirected to the intended URL once after the user logs in
        $request->session()->put('url.intended', url()->previous());

        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()] , 401);
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }
}
```